# MediaWiki edit hook (EditPage::showEditForm:initial)

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am building an extension for MediaWiki. While building this I added another hook

```
$wgHooks['EditPage::showEditForm:initial'][] = 'FrontPageMessage::onEditPage::showEditForm:initial';
```

After adding this hook I get this error.

```
[f0667f54] /****/index.php?title=Main_Page&action=edit MWException from line 182 
of C:\xampp\htdocs\****\includes\Hooks.php: Invalid callback
FrontPageMessage::onEditPage::showEditForm:initial in hooks for
EditPage::showEditForm:initial

    Backtrace:

    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\****\includes\EditPage.php(2418): Hooks::run(string, array)
      #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\****\includes\EditPage.php(582): EditPage->showEditForm()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\****\includes\actions\EditAction.php(58): EditPage->edit()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\****\includes\MediaWiki.php(490): EditAction->show()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\****\includes\MediaWiki.php(287): MediaWiki->performAction(Article, Title)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\****\includes\MediaWiki.php(714): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\****\includes\MediaWiki.php(508): MediaWiki->main()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\****\index.php(41): MediaWiki->run()
#8 {main}
```

This error only happens when I add this hook to my extension. The rest of my extension seems to be in working order. I assume this is happening because I have improperly used this hook. Does anyone know if this is the case, and if not what is causing this error?

Comment: What would you expect to happen? `FrontPageMessage::onEditPage::showEditForm:initial` is not a function name.

Comment: @Tgr Clearly I need to do more research into this. I am very new to working with MediaWiki and seem to have a base misunderstanding of it. Any where you might point me with up to date information on development?

Comment: PHP's documentation page on [callables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). You probably looked at the [hook documentation page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/EditPage::showEditForm:initial) but that's auto-generated and apparently not prepared for hooks which have `:` in their names.

Comment: (Hook documentations should be fixed now.)

Comment: More generally (and less usefully) you could look at [How to become a MediaWiki hacker](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/How_to_become_a_MediaWiki_hacker).

Comment: Well thank you for your help. I believe this should be a very good starting point.